# sir give me Q. "Write a procedure named expensive_books which finds the details of books with a price is more than the average price in pl/sql"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, plsql-package

I tried a lot but i can't get answer

I write this program and I also write "set serveroutput on;" but this is not showing output

[this is table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNeL5.png)

and this is code

```
declare
    name book.book_title%type;
    price book.book_price%type;
    p book.book_price%type;

PROCEDURE expensive_books(name in out book.book_title%type,price in out book.book_price%type,p in out number)
is 
begin
expensive_books(name,price,p);
select avg(book_price),book_price,book_title into p,price,name from book;
 end;
 begin
 for i in 1..5 loop
    if  p > price then
     dbms_output.put_line('Book Name='||name);
    end if; 
    end loop;
 end;
/
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question - funny that "expensive" is defined as "price above average". Many years ago I lived in a communist country, where the dictator was mad that there were still counties with agricultural output below the national average. At least that guy had an excuse - he didn't finish fourth grade.

Comment: why are you calling expensive_books procedure inside the procedure itself?

Comment: And why don't you call the procedure within your block? And where do you find the average price? Also, how is this related to PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Im student that's why I have doubts

Answer (score 0):

> this is not showing output

You never call the procedure.

If you format the PL/SQL block:

```sql
declare
  name book.book_title%type;
  price book.book_price%type;
  p book.book_price%type;

  PROCEDURE expensive_books(
    name in out book.book_title%type,
    price in out book.book_price%type,
    p in out number
  )
  is 
  begin
    expensive_books(name,price,p);
    select book_price,book_title into price,name from book;
  end;
begin
  for i in 1..5 loop
    if  p > price then
      dbms_output.put_line('Book Name='||name);
    end if; 
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Then you can see that in the body of the PL/SQL block (between the `BEGIN` and the final `END`) that you never call the procedure so your code is effectively:

```sql
declare
  name book.book_title%type;
  price book.book_price%type;
  p book.book_price%type;
begin
  for i in 1..5 loop
    if  p > price then
      dbms_output.put_line('Book Name='||name);
    end if; 
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Since `p` and `price` are not initialised then they will have `NULL` values and the `IF` statement is effectively `IF NULL > NULL THEN` and that will never be true (since `NULL` compared to anything is never true) so nothing will be output.

If you want to display something then you need to call the procedure and set the value of `p`, `price` and `name` (and your procedure never sets the `p` value and also calls itself at every iteration so would get into a infinite loop if you did call it).

Answer (score 0):

Better to do the querying in a single query:

```
begin
  for x in (select book_title, book_price
            from books
            where book_price > (select avg(book_price)
                                from books)
            and rownum <=5) loop

    dbms_output.put_line(x.book_title);
  end loop;
end;
```